# How does Golos, Tireless Pilgrim interact with double-faced cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-double-faced-cards

From the Ixalan set, we received double faced cards with lands on the back.  I believe they count as all types on both sides while not on the field.  Therefore:

When [Golos, Tireless Pilgrim](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=466980) activates his ETB and I pick [Gold-Forge Garrison](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439843) as my land, which side does it enter as?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You can't pick a double-faced card that is a land only on the back

Double-faced cards only count as their front face while not on the battlefield. From [the rules on double-faced cards](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr711/#4a):

> **711.4a** While a double-faced card is outside the game, in a zone other than the battlefield, or on the battlefield with its front face up, it has only the characteristics of its front face.

You cannot choose Gold-Forge Garrison as your land, as its front face is not a land.

I think you're getting DFC rules mixed up with [split cards](https://scryfall.com/search?q=is%3Asplit), which [do have the attributes of both halves](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr708/#4) while they're not being cast:

> **708.4** In every zone except the stack, the characteristics of a split card are those of its two halves combined. This is a change from previous rules.

### A double-faced card you chose would enter front face up

A double-faced card always enters with its front face up *unless* it enters “transformed”. If you choose a double-faced card that is a land on its front face, like [Westvale Abbey](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWestvale%20Abbey%5d), Golos would not put it onto the battlefield transformed, so you would get the front face.

> **711.8** A double-faced card enters the battlefield with its front face up by default. If a spell or ability puts it onto the battlefield “transformed,” it enters the battlefield with its back face up.

Comment: Ah quite right, I was thinking of the Split/Fuse cards.  That's a shame, I was really excited about having Golos pull all the Ixalan lands right onto the field :(

Answer (score 2):

The Ixalan double faced cards are not treated as lands unless they are on the battlefield and transformed.

> 711.4a While a double-faced card is outside the game, in a zone other than the battlefield, or on the battlefield with its front face up, it has only the characteristics of its front face.